# Discord - Add into users nickname then remove added word

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I created an AFK command for my discord bot but I am struggling to figure out how I would add "[AFK]" into the current users **nickname**.

Below is what I have but this takes the users discord name **instead of nickname** and adds "[AFK]" to it.

```
message.member.setNickname(`[AFK] ${message.author.username}`)
```

Then I would like to remove [AFK] from their nickname when the "if afk" statement is triggered (I have already wrote the if statement) but keep the rest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `message.member` to get the [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) from the message.

```js
message.member.nickname
```

would give you the nickname of the user, but it will return `null` if the user has none. You can also use

```js
message.member.displayName
```

which would give you the nickname, or their username if they don't have one.

Comment: @SebastiaanYN great first answer by the way :)

Answer (score 2):

You should simply use .replace to replace the [AFK] from the string:

```
const currentNickname = message.member.nickname;

const newNickname = currentNickname.replace('[AFK]', '');

message.member.setNickname(newNickname);
```

---

You could also do it like this:

```
message.member.setNickname(message.member.displayName);
```

This gives the user his current nickname. If the user hasn't a nickname, the new nickname will be the Discord username of this specific user.